# Averaging items from multiple lists

Tags: xls

I understand that this site is probably overkill for my simple question, but I can't find the answer online at all.

If I have several ranked lists, like five people's list of their top ten movies...how do I find the average rank of the individual items (movies) when each list does not necessarily have all of the same items on it?  I am trying to do this in Excel 2007.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "each list does not necessarily have all of the same items on it", but you probably want to start by looking at Excel's AVERAGE function:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/average-HP005208994.aspx

They go over some basic and more complex usage there.